# Unimodality of a function of a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

I am taking an interest in the following problem:

Consider a real matrix with non-negative entries $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}_+^{d \times d}$, with $d \in \mathbb{N}$.
For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$\boldsymbol{P}_\boldsymbol{A}(k) \doteq \frac{(\boldsymbol{A}^T)^k \boldsymbol{A}^k}{\rho(\boldsymbol{A})^{2k}},$$
where $\rho(\boldsymbol{A})$ is the Perron-Frobenius root of the matrix.
By construction, $\boldsymbol{P}_\boldsymbol{A}(k)$ is going to be symmetric. Writing $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_d$ its real spectrum, always $|\lambda_1| \lor|\lambda_d| \leq 1$.
Define now for $1\leq i \leq d- 1$, 
$$\phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k) \doteq \frac{\lambda_i - \lambda_{i+1}}{k}.$$
I would like to show that the function 
$$\phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k) \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_+$$ is **unimodal for fixed $i$**, in the sense where:
Let $k_0$ such that $\phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}$ achieves its maximum at $k_0$, for $k \geq k_0$, $\phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k) \geq \phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k+1)$, and for $k \leq k_0$, $\phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k) \geq \phi^{(i)}_\boldsymbol{A}(k-1)$.

Comment: If $A$ is strictly upper triangular, then the denominator of $P_A(k)$ vanishes, and the numerator vanishes for large enough $k$. So you have to eliminate that possibility. But in general (even aside from the upper triangular case), $\rho(A)$ has little to do with $\rho (A^k (A^T)^k)^{1/2k}$, so the function is unlikely to be tractible.

Comment: Thank you David Handelman. Do you know of additional structure besides symmetry of $\boldsymbol{A}$ that would lead to some connection between the two ?